# PhoneGap Build Android Select

Tags: cordova, select, phonegap-build

I have built a phonegap app using phonegap 2.0

Works Great!

when updating to phonegap 2.2 i loose functionality of drop downs

her is an example of one of my drop downs

```
<select name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$ddlAgent" onchange="javascript:setTimeout('__doPostBack(\'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder2$ddlAgent\',\'\')', 0)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_ddlAgent" style="width:90%;text-align:center;">
<option selected="selected" value="1">Option1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">Option1</option>
<option selected="selected" value="1">Option1</option>

</select>
```

I don't thinks it s a config issue, is it an issue with the latest version of phonegap? or is it in my code? Here is a start... Here is my head

```
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-    scale=1.0"/>
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="images/splash/splash-icon.png"> 
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash/splash-screen.png"     media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" /> 
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/splash/splash-screen@2x.png" media="        (max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" /> 
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes"/>
<title>DCC On-The-Go</title>

<link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style/retina.css" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:     2)" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="style/buttons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="style/photoswipe.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<script src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/easing.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/tweetable.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/roundabout.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/contact.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/swipe.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/klass.min.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/photoswipe.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/retina.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/custom.js"></script>



</head>
```

I am also going to try in 2.3 and 2.1 now to test other versions...

look forward to peoples thoughts, inputs and discussions on phonegap 2.2 and this issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was at some point compiled with a config.xml and build.phonegap.com does not allow building without the config.xml once it has been used... New build and were away !!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check your html, css and js. Phonegap shouldn't interfere with simple features like drop down. Plus, you don't even include cordova.js in your html head.

Comment: thanks for your feedback, this is a webpage which we load in childbrowser, thus its not "compile" as such with phonegap. Even with the addition of a cordova.js file, I don't believe it has no effect as the file doesn't sit within the file group injected into phonegap build? Thoughts would be appreciated, Regards, Henry